# Java compile error invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

Tags: java

I have written simple java program in which I am referring below jar files 
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-configuration-1.9.jar
commons-collections4-4.4.jar
I have place these file in my lib folder path and set CLASSPATH variable in .profile file.
Also given execute permission to all jar files.
But still got below error while compiling my java file.

**error: error reading /app/produagg/aggregator/java/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
error: error reading /app/produagg/aggregator/java/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
error: error reading /app/produagg/aggregator/java/lib/commons-configuration-1.9.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
error: error reading /app/produagg/aggregator/java/lib/commons-collections4-4.4.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)**

Why this error is coming ? 
The program is working fine in Development and SIT and preproduction environment.

Comment: It's hard to say but my first step debugging it would be to go to that directory and examine the jar files to see if they are valid, truncated, missing, or have somehow gotten overwritten with other data.

Comment: Why are you compiling your source code in each environment? Compile your source code once - preferably on a build server with a predictable configuration - and make a jar file with your classes (or better, some deployment unit containing your entire deployable, such as a .tar.gz, .rpm, Docker image, etc.) - then deploy that to each environment.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your JAR files are corrupted. Check the size of your `commons-logging-1.2.jar`. It should be 61829 bytes.

```sh
% wget -S -O /dev/null 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar' 2>&1 | fgrep Content-Length:
  Content-Length: 61829
```

MD5 sum should be `040b4b4d8eac886f6b4a2a3bd2f31b00`:

```sh
% md5sum commons-logging-1.2.jar
040b4b4d8eac886f6b4a2a3bd2f31b00  commons-logging-1.2.jar
```